# Markdown presentation builder producing PDF

Tags: presentations

I'm looking for a OSX/Unix presentation software with which I can:

1. write my slides in Mardown
2. export the presentation in a PDF file
3. have code highlighting

[showoff](https://github.com/schacon/showoff) does all this but does not seem very maintained, I get various errors when trying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a fork of showoff: [parade](https://github.com/burtlo/parade)

EDIT:

From a post on [jumpstartlab](http://jumpstartlab.com/news/archives/2013/03/27/parade-version-0-10) from Franklin Webber who made the fork on github:

> Parade is presentation software powered by Sinatra with slides written
>   in Markdown.  Parade 0.10 brings with it better support for mobile
>   devices and quite a few common slide formats.
>
> Parade is a fork of Scott Chacon's Showoff. The work I started was
>   initially to address two of it's shortcomings:
>
> - Lack of GitHub Flavored Markdown
> - Static HTML and PDF generation did not inline images and styles
>
> Along the way a number of other remarkable features were added:
>
> - Easy support for themes and plugins
> - Better presentation support for smaller form-factor devices
> - More default slide formats
>
> […]